# Preventing access to include files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm having a problem with .htaccess file rewrite rules. I want to have one .htaccess file in my root directory and to have rule over there to stop people to be able to access files directly over browser. So, for example I have folder blah/includes/file.php and .htaccess file is in blah/ folder, I want to prevent people to be able to just type in browser blah/includes/file.php and get that file, but also I want my functions in app to be able to use those files. I understand that is almost impossible for them to know exact name of my include files but I would like to be sure.
Thanks in advance.

here is my code which is not responding:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    ## Enable Mod Rewrite, this is only required once in each .htaccess file
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    ## Test for access to includes directory
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /includes/ .*$ [NC]
    ## Test that file requested has php extension
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.+\.php$
    ## Forbid Access
    RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Note: I'm testing in localhost if that is maybe important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in the first RewriteCond you have a space after /includes/, which throws an error.

BUT: I wouldn't use `%{THE_REQUEST}`, as it contains the HTTP Request (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Use `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead.

So, if you want to forbid access to `/<folder>/include/*.php`, you can use just this code:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]+/includes/.*\.php$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,NS,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Assuming your .htaccess lies in the blah/ folder.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that space. But after I changed I'm still able to enter include folder and his php files. Also tried your solution, same thing. Do you have idea what that can be?

Comment: Assuming you have the file `/foo/includes/file.php`, with the above code it worked fine on my dev server. What's your exact file structure?

Comment: Here is my path to the file.php
http://localhost/education/appFolder/include/file.php
My .htaccess is in appFolder which is app I'm using.

Comment: Is there any chance that this is connected with overriding Apache or something online?

Comment: Ok, it won't work if have more than one directory level, but you can just use this code, if it fits your needs: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /includes/.*\.php$ [NC]` This should cover every PHP-file in any subfolder named "includes".

Comment: Shocker, thank you for all your responses. I've tried that too, and still I'm not getting what I want. Still I can directly get in to my .php files inside /insludes directory. What I have and it's working is 'Options -Indexes', so I don't have dir listing. I will try on my two online servers, maybe that will change something. I will let you know here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be just to put a one-line **.htaccess** file in your **includes** directory:

`deny from all`

The other alternative is to place your **includes** folder outside of your web-accessible directory.

```
/home/
    /username/
        /includes/
        /public_html/
            /index.php
```

If you *still* want to use a `RewriteRule`, then this is the one you’d use:

`RewriteRule ^includes/ - [F,L,NC]`

Which would return a `401 Forbidden` response trying to access a URI that begin with `includes`.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^includes [F,L,NC]` should be `RewriteRule ^includes/ - [F,L,NC]`, otherwise it won't work.